# How to show the both positive and negative values for a stacked area chart in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to create a stacked area chart to show both the positive and negatives values. However, the negatives are not showing below zero? Can anyone help to explain why this is so and how can I correct it? Please click below to see the screenshot and the set of data. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1YOR.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73oqN.jpg)

Comment: Hi and welcome to SU. Please edit your post to show a screenshot of your data. It may be that a stacked area chart is not appropriate.

Comment: Try formatting your axis... maybe it's set to a minimum of 0. Regardless, this may look better as a different type of chart such as stacked bar.

Answer (score 0):

**:Caveat:** *Since you have not shared any sample data with us therefore I've use this one.*

[image]

**N.B.**

- For better data visualization adjust the Scale.
- To get Negative value on chart you must have Negative value in used data range.
- You may create other type of chart also using both Negative and Positive data.